# Why do I get this error when I try to use db_change_field()?

Tags: database

My Drupal installation has a table with a field `title` of type varchar and length of 255.

For some custom process, I need to increase the length to 500 characters.

I tried doing so with the following code:

```
function mymodule_schema_alter(&$schema){
    if( isset($schema['field_data_field_document_title']) ){
        db_change_field('field_data_field_document_title', 'field_document_title_value', 'field_document_title_value', 
            array(
                'length' => 11,
            )
        );

    }
}
```

Originally I had that code in my .module file. When I flushed caches I could verify using the DEVEL module that my field length changed. But in phpmyadmin the field length remained 255.

Then I migrated the function to the .install file. I execute *run updates* and get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL' at line 1: ALTER TABLE {field_data_field_document_title} CHANGE `field_document_title_value` `field_document_title_value` DEFAULT NULL; Array ( ) in db_change_field() (line 3020 of /var/www/Intranet/includes/database/database.inc).

I could really use some help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because you aren't using `db_change_field()` with the correct arguments. For example, if you look at [`block_update_7003()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.install/function/block_update_7003/7.x), you will see it calls the function as follows.

```
  db_change_field('block', 'weight', 'weight', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'description' => 'Block weight within region.',
  ), array(
    'indexes' => array(
      'list' => array('theme', 'status', 'region', 'weight', 'module'),
    ),
  ));
```

The last argument is the full array defining the field, not just the part that you need to change.

As the description for `block_update_7003()` says, its purpose is changing the weight column to normal int. If your code were correct, `block_update_7003()` should use the following call.

```
  db_change_field('block', 'weight', 'weight', array(
    'type' => 'int',
  ));
```

Also, [`hook_schema_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7.x) should be used to alter the schema, not adding or removing database fields. Drupal doesn't use that hook, but the example code is clear enough.

```
function hook_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  // Add field to existing schema.
  $schema['users']['fields']['timezone_id'] = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'description' => 'Per-user timezone configuration.',
  );
}
```

The description of the hook is probably not clear, since it doesn't say in which way the schema should be changed, but since is talking of `$schema`, the idea behind that hook is that it alters what returned from `hook_schema()`, which is what an alter hook normally does: Change the values returned from another hook.

It is then `hook_install()` or `hook_update_N()` that effectively changes the database table.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation for `hook_schema_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7.x): `db_change_field()` is not supposed to be used there, instead change the `$schema` array to the required structure.

```
function mymodule_schema_alter(&$schema){
    if( isset($schema['field_data_field_document_title']) ){
        $schema['field_data_field_document_title']['fields']['field_data_field_document_title_value']['length'] = 500;
    }
}
```

However, if the module is already installed and has existing data (seems like this is the case), then a call to `db_change_field()` inside a [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) implementation is necessary to update the schema.

```
function mymodule_update_7100() {
    $table = drupal_get_schema('field_data_field_document_title', TRUE);
    db_change_field('field_data_field_document_title', 'field_document_title_value', 'field_document_title_value', $table['fields']['field_document_title_value']);
}
```

Note (if there is existing data): both these functions need to be included in mymodule.install, as the second function depends on the first: the change of field length made in `mymodule_schema_alter()` will be included in the table schema returned by `drupal_get_schema()`.

Comment: Note: the code samples in the question do not meet Drupal coding standards, I thought it more important to meet the OP's coding style in my answer, despite that being incorrect. See: https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards

Comment: Thank you for helping out. However, I tried both approaches you suggested and only the hook_update_n approach seemed to work but it resulted  the same PDOException as stated in my question

Comment: Might be that db_change_field() requires the entire field spec (not just what has changed), that shouldn't be too hard. I'll update the code sample.

Comment: db_change_field() does require the entire field spec. This is where the error comes from.

Note that any changes made to the field in hook_update_N() (or wherever you put your db_change_field() code) should be reflected by altering the $schema array in hook_schema_alter(). This is because various functions that call drupal_get_schema(), in particular drupal_write_record(), require that the accurate schema be reflected through changes in hook_schema_alter(). hook_schema_alter() is not for actually making the changes though, it's just for telling Drupal what changes have been made.